# where is extended_tweet in twitter metadata

Tags: python, dictionary, twitter, tweets

I am trying to parse the `full_text` from `extended_tweet` and I thought it is one of main attributes like `created_at` and `id`. However I found out that `retweeted_status` also contains `extended_tweet`. So I read twitter document, but don't see explanation yet. Which attribute contains `extended_tweet`?

Answer (score 0):

With the REST API, you'll see `full_text` instead of `text` if the tweet is an extended tweet. The only time you would see an actual `extended_tweet` property was if you were using the streaming API or Gnip. Twitters documentation on [Tweet Updates](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/tweet-updates) provides more detailed explanation.